# python third-party modules installed but not importing

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I am new to Python and following the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python course. I am trying to install third-party modules and I assume the pip tool is properly installed in my system because it came bundled with my python 3.8.

Let me start by saying that yes, I have Python successfully installed, and it is in C:\Users\izask\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8.

Here I find my first snag: When I type    C:\Users\izask>python --version    in my prompt command, I expect to get a version number, but what I get is a blank line and a new prompt, like this:

```
C:\Users\izask>python --version

C:\Users\izask>
```

This confuses me. I don't know if this is normal behavior or if something is not right in my installation.

I had a couple more snags that I think I have worked through successfully, such as adding the path to the scripts into my PATH, and proceeded to install some modules, apparently successfully. See, for example:

C:\Users\izask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts>pip.exe install pyzmail36
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmail36 in c:\users\izask\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\izask\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pyzmail36) (47.1.0)

I am not quite sure why it shows it installed in two different locations, but never mind. What worries me is that, when I then go to the Python shell and try to import pyzmail36, I get an error:

> > > import pyzmail36
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in 
> > > import pyzmail36
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyzmail36'

This is just an example. I get the same error with some other modules that are apparently also installed, and I also have some modules successfully imported (no errors in the python shell when imported).

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you,

Iza

Comment: What you're doing wrong is assuming "yes, I have Python successfully installed" - when everything after that suggests that may not be the case. What do you see when you run `where python` on the command line from `C:\Users\izask`?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I get a path when I try "where python": C:\Users\izask\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe   Note that this is a different path than what I get when I right-click on Python on my Windows Explorer, which is the path I wrote at the top of my original post.  I get nothing when I type %echo% (see below).

Comment: It looks like you tried to install Python in a couple of different ways and now there's multiple copies on your system, with some confusion about what's what. I'd recommend uninstalling all of them, ensuring `python` on the command line results in `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` - then install Python again, putting it in an appropriate location. Then create a virtual environment and put the package in it, or install in the global environment if that's what you prefer (I'd generally recommend against it)

Answer (score 0):

> When I type C:\Users\izask>python --version in my prompt command, I expect to get a version number, but what I get is a blank line

This is the first red flag. This shows that you don't have python installed in your command line.
When you type `py` in your CLI, python will not start up.

Here's what I followed to fix my issue:

If you don;t have python added to your path then you'll need to do so first. Type `%echo%` and see if python is there in your path, if not then [add it](https://superuser.com/questions/611069/python-not-in-command-line-even-though-it-is-in-path).

Restart and type python --version again, it will show you the version.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. I get absolutely nothing when I type %echo% but I get a path when I type "where python": C:\Users\izask\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe  It is a different path from what  I get when I open the program location from Windows Explorer, which is C:\Users\izask\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8   I am very confused.